# Partial derivative operator

Tags: derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

Maybe a dumb question but I'm relatively new to this topic so I'd still ask this:

I saw it here: [Wirtinger derivatives - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wirtinger_derivatives&oldid=1082805301#Functions_of_one_complex_variable)

[image]

> ###### Functions of one complex variable
>
> **Definition 1.** Consider the complex plane $\mathbb{C} \equiv \mathbb{R}^2 = \{ (x,y) | x,y \in \mathbb{R} \}$. The Wirtinger derivatives are defined as the following linear partial differential operators of first order:
> \begin{align}
> \frac{\partial}{\partial z} &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)\\
> \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)
> \end{align}

In ordinary derivatives, I know $\frac{d}{dx}$ is an operator which "operates" on something, e.g. $\frac{dx^2}{dx} = 2x$ but $\frac{d}{dx}$ in itself has no "value." It only yields a "value" when it is applied to some function. $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\frac{d}{dy}$ would have no value unless there's some function it is operating on, right? It is the confusion I have with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} $ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$.
That is why I'm confused with what is $\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)$. Where are $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$   operating at?

Why does this $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ seem to already have a value?
Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ the same as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ where $f$ is in the domain? So that means $f$ is predefined (?). So $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$  is the same for all $f$ in the domain? Then that would be absurd, right (?)

I'm sorry I'm really just new to this. But I know how to take partial derivatives, I'm just confused why $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ seems like treated as a variable in $\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)$. I see it as an operator. Maybe I got lost in translation -- I mean, notations.

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ are differential operators, that is, linear operators that map any function $f$ to the corresponding partial derivative

Comment: so $f$ must be predefined for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ to have something to operate on, right?

Comment: am I getting it? (is my understanding correct)

Comment: no, $f$ not need to be predefined, the operators act on any differentiable function. By example let $C^1(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R})$ the space of functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ such that both partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)$ exists and are continuous, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is a linear operator that map every function in $C^1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ into the space of continuous functions $C(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R})$

Comment: I am generally ignorant in this area.  However, as an outside observer, it seems as if you are having trouble with certain abstract concepts.  I see no reason why the normal *cure* in such Math contexts would not be effective here.  I advise elbow grease, perhaps $20$ times.  That is, manually examine $20$ situations/problems that involve $~\frac{\partial}{\partial x}~$ for specific functions, and actually **see** the explicit results of such analysis.  Then, rinse and repeat with $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$

Comment: Thanks @Masacroso

Comment: in short, given some domain and codomain, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is a **function** (that operates over sets of differentiable functions)

Comment: thanks also @user2661923, yeah, I just saw this without an introduction or definition of it, I had to solve a problem where $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$  was not explicitly shown. But when I looked for hints, the answer involves $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$. I'd like to read the definition of $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$   and do some exercises. I'd appreciate if anyone could send me links of some resources.

Comment: I should point out that in my experience about $50\%$ of Math texts are written by authors who do not express the underlying Math concepts as well as they might.  Further, if the specific concept, if and of itself is convoluted, this worsens the situation.  Often, a *valid naked definition* will evolve that is difficult for the Math student to wrap their intuition around.  In my experience, the only cure here is (again) the elbow grease of the exercises.

Comment: I know how to take partial derivatives, I'm just confused why $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ seems like treated as a variable in $\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)$. I see it as an operator.

Comment: @automorp15m Please do not vandalize posted questions, including your own. Rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

Just like we can define functions as linear combinations of other functions, say $f = x^2 + 3x$ (where $x^2$ and $3x$ are other functions) we can define *operators* in terms of other operators.

So, we know what $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is: It's the operator taking a function $f(x,y)$ and returning $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ (the [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) in the $x$ direction). Similarly, we know what $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is. It's the operator sending a function $f(x,y)$ to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ (the partial derivative in the $y$ direction).

Then from these, we want to *define* a new operator: $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$. We define it as

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = 
\frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right )
$$

and we apply it to a function in exactly the way you expect:

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 
\frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right ) f =
\frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right )
$$

So, for a super concrete example, can you see why
$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (x^2 y) = \frac{1}{2} \left ( 2xy - i x^2 \right )$?

In fact, this idea of defining new operators in terms of old operators is *extremely* fruitful, and we can push it much further than just taking linear combinations of operators, as we've done here. You might want to google the [operator calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_calculus) for more.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is the same as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$  ?

Comment: @automorp15m In analogy, your comment's question is sort of like asking whether $f$ is the same as $f(1)$.  Do you understand how $f$ and $f(1)$ are not the same?

Comment: in ordinary derivatives, $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\frac{d}{dy}$ would have no value unless there's some function it is operating on, right? It is the confusion  I have with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$

Comment: It is notation for the maps $f \mapsto { \partial f \over \partial x}$, $f \mapsto { \partial f \over \partial y}$ respectively.

Comment: that is why I'm confused with what is $\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)$. Where are $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$   operating at?

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat

Comment: Thank all! 
 I just saw this without an introduction or definition of it, I had to solve a problem where $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$  was not explicitly shown. But when I looked for hints, the answer involves $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$. I'd like to read the definition of $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$   and do some exercises. I'd appreciate if anyone could send me links of some resources.

Comment: @automorp15m A function "has no value" unless you give it an input. Yet we can talk about the function $f$ without having to specify the input like so: $f(5)$. In the same way, a differential operator like $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ "has no value" until we've given it _both_ a function _and_ a point, yet we can still talk about it as its own object.

Comment: by "value" I mean a "result". Not necessarily a number.

Comment: thanks @Arthur .

Comment: I know how to take partial derivatives, I'm just confused why $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ seems like treated as a variable in $\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)$. I see it as an operator.

Comment: would it be more clear if instead we defined $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{\partial f }{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right )$? That's very literally all we're doing.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor yes! That's exactly what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B^A$ the set of functions from $A$ to $B$, and suppose that $B$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$, then $B^A$ inherits an structure of vector space where if $f,g\in B^A$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$ then the functions $f+g$ and $\lambda\cdot  f$ are defined as

$$
(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x),\quad (\lambda \cdot f)(x):=\lambda \cdot f(x)\tag1
$$

for every $x\in A$ (usually we omit the dot and just writes $\lambda f$ instead of $\lambda \cdot f$). Now let $V:=\mathbb{C}^{(\mathbb{R}^2)}$ and note that $V$ inherits a vector space structure from $\mathbb{C}$ as discussed above, that is, $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and define

$$
A:=\left\{f\in V:\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\text{  and }\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\text{ both exists }\right\}\tag2
$$

Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ belong to the vector space of functions $V^A$ so we can define the function $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}:=\frac1{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$. Then, as $V^A$ is also a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, for every $f\in A$ from (1) we have that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(f)=\frac1{2}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f)-\frac{i}2\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial y}(f)\tag3
$$

where we generally writes $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f$ instead of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f)$.

Comment: masacroso thank you!  :)